# Is it possible to 're-push' yanked version gem published at rubygems.org at same version?

Tags: ruby, release, publishing

[This](https://github.com/ap-automator/jekyll-rushed-analytics) is what I am talking about.
My attempt is to repush the exact same version, 0.1.12.
My previous push is invalid, it broken gem what I push.
I highly want to publish this version, like I already implement the sem-versioning.

the pushing process yield:

```
Repushing of gem versions is not allowed. Please use a new version and retry
```

So is it possible? if not what is the main use of yanking a submitted gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can not re-submit the same version number, this is made on purpose for security reasons, avoiding maintainers to upload the same version without getting noticed by the developers. So you will need to release a new version of your gem

Comment: yes, that makes sense a lot. but I found the trick, I publish a lower version [see](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-rushed-analytics/versions) as proof. In contrast, it **highly highly** discouraged.

Comment: That's not necessarily true, imagine rails, which is running 7 as the latest version, but still supporting 6, 5, and 4 for security patches, so they still publish "lower" versions